# Why does this proof work: Closed unit ball in $C_0$ is not compact

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, banach-spaces, compactness

I know that this question has been asked to death, and multiple solutions are given, but I still don't understand why the "standard" proof works

Following [Show that the closed unit ball $B[0,1]$ in $C[0,1]$ is not compact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1283583/show-that-the-closed-unit-ball-b0-1-in-c0-1-is-not-compact)

---

Let $C_o([0,1])$ be the space of continuous functions on $[0,1]$. Define $\|f\| = \sup\{|f(x)| x \in [0,1]]\}$

Let $B[0,1] = \{f \in C_o|\|f\|\leq 1\}$, show that this Closed, Unit ball in $C_o$ is not compact.

**Proof Sketch:**

> Let $\{f_n\} \subset C_o, f_n = x^n, x \in [0,1]$, then $f_n \in C_o,
>  \|f_n\| = 1 \thinspace \forall n$, so $f_n \in B([0,1]) \thinspace \forall n$
>
> But $f_n \to f \notin C_o$. So $B([0,1])$ is not compact.

Three questions:

1. if $f_n \to f \notin C_o$, wouldn't that mean $B([0,1])$ is not closed in the first place (contradicts with assumption)?
2. How does the above implies that no subsequence converges in $B([0,1])$
3. Is the proof sketch essentially correct?

Comment: 1. No: points not in $C_0$ are irrelevant to whether a set is closed in $C_0$. \\ 2. If a sequence in $C_0$ converges in norm to a point $g$ of $C_0$, then it also converges pointwise to $g$. But every subsequence of $\langle f_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges pointwise to $f$ and therefore does *not* converge pointwise to any $g\in C_0$. Thus, no subsequence can converge in norm to a point of $C_0$. \\ 3. Yes.

Comment: $(f_n)_n$ is not a Cauchy sequence in $C[0,1]$ , which has the topology of uniform convergence, but it converges pointwise to a  discontinuous real function $f$.  Any subsequence of $(f_n)_n$ that converged in $C[0,1]$ would have to converge uniformly to $f$ ,which would make $f$ continuous. So there is no such subsequence.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott So in simple terms, even though $\{f_n\}$ is in $B([0,1])$, no subsequence of $(f_n)$ is in $B([0,1])$, therefore $B([0,1])$ is not compact. I guess thats what I needed to fill in the part between $But...So...$

Comment: @Lookbehindyou: The subsequences themselves are all in $B([0,1])$; it’s just that none of them is a convergent sequence in $C_0$, i.e., none of them has a limit in the metric space $C_0$.

Comment: @Brain M.Scott Yeah sorry I meant to say no subsequence of $(f_n)$ converges in the ball.

Comment: Instead of getting into subsequence part ,can I used contrapositive of Bolzano-Weirstrass property.Means ${f_n}$ is infinite subset of $B[0,1]$ which does not have limit in $B[0,1]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another exmple to show that $B[0,1]$ is not compact: For $n\in N $ let $0<a_n<b_n<a_{n+1}<1.$ For $x\in [0,a_n]\cup [a_{n+1},1]$ let $f_n(x)=0.$ For $x\in [a_n,b_n]$ let $f_n(x)$ be linear with $f_n(b_n)=1.$ For $x\in [b_n,a_{n+1}]$ let $f_n(x)$ be linear. Then $1=\|f_n\|=\|f_n-f_m\|$ for $m,n\in N$ with $m\ne n$. So $\{f_n:n\in N\}$ is an infinite closed discrete  subspace of the space $B[0,1].$ A metric space with an infinite closed discrete subspace is not a compact space.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The proof sketch is correct If a subsequence of $(f_n)$ converges, it converges pointwise towards $f$ which is not continue at 1, so $B(0,1)\subset C([0,1])$ is not compact.